# Mouseover shows image in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in files | filter :'image'">
    <div class="file-tag-baloon1" ng-mouseover="hoverImg(image.id)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
      <span style="width: 200px;">
        <a ng-show="hideHoveredImage==false;" class="hover-title">{{hoverTitle}}
          <img class="hover-image" src="{{hoveredImage}}">
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.hoverOut = function () {
  $scope.hideHoveredImage = true;
  $scope.hoveredImage = "";
}
$scope.hoverImg = function (id) {
  $scope.hoveredImage = FileService.getFile(json, id);
}
```

I wrote a function to hove the image on mouseover. But the problem is If I have 4`{{hoverTitle}}`, four times the hovering image div appears ,i need the hovering image per index also I wanted it to be exactly at top of the `$scope.hiverTitle` . Any examples or solution will help me better.

Comment: could you type your question more clearly please ?